# Looping Through Specific Combo Boxes (Array)

Tags: ms-access, vba

I need to requery only specific combo boxes in a form, which I want to have in an array. The combo boxes are not in order and I do not want to loop through all combo boxes in the form.

The best way I can compare it to is the following in Excel for looping through specified worksheets:

```
Dim ws As Worksheet
For Each ws In Worksheets("Sheet1", "Sheet4", "Sheet7")
    ' do something
Next ws
```

I cannot figure out how to do this in Access. I have tried variations of this:

```
For Each Control In Me.Controls(Me.cbo1, Me.cbo4, Me.cbo7)
    Control.Requery
Next Control
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a lightweight approach, you can put the combo box names in a comma-separated string, `Split()` the string into an array, and then loop through the array members.

```vb
Const cstrNames As String = "cbo1,cbo4,cbo7"
Dim varName As Variant

For Each varName In Split(cstrNames, ",")
    Me.Controls(varName).Requery
Next
```

If you want to share that list between other procedures in your form, you can make the string a module-level constant instead of declaring it again in each procedure.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of approaches, but you could put them in a `Collection`:

```
Private Sub Command7_Click()
    Dim coll As New Collection
    Dim item As ComboBox

    coll.Add Me.Combo1
    coll.Add Me.Combo5
    coll.Add Me.Combo3

    For Each item In coll
        item.Requery
    Next item
End Sub
```

Comment: Works perfectly! My next dilemma now is how to get this Collection to be accessible to other Subs.

Comment: You can just move the declaration of the Collection outside of a specific Sub, at the top of the form's module. Use the Private modifier so that it is private to the form. You can do the same Hans's constant.