# VB Is it possible to use a loop to control multiple form controls?

Tags: forms, excel, loops, excel-2010, vba

I'm working in Excel 2010 and it's VB editor. I have a form with 6 comboboxes and when I initialize the form the same thing needs to happen for all 6 comboboxes. Currently I have to write the same lines of code for the various comboboxes as demonstrated below.

```
Private Sub Form_Initialize()
    Dim Table As ListObject
    Set Table = ThisWorkBook.Worksheets("Sheet1").ListObjects("Table1")
    Dim Rows As Integer
    Rows = Table.ListRows.Count
    Dim i As Integer

    With Me.ComboBox_1
        .Clear
        .Value = Empty
        For i = 1 to Rows
            .AddItem Table.DataBodyRange(i, 1)
        Next i
    End With

    With Me.ComboBox_2
        .Clear
        .Value = Empty
        for i = 1 to Rows
            .AddItem Table.DataBodyRange(i, 1)
        Next i
     End With

    'This repeats for another 4 comboboxes (ComboBox_3, ComboBox_4,
    'ComboBox_5 and ComboBox_6)

 End Sub
```

It becomes very annoying to write the same code over and over again and becomes especially annoying when I want to alter the procedure for the comboboxes and have to update 5 others also.

Is it possible to write a single code that loops for each combobox?

Comment: Something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19624728/looping-through-specific-combo-boxes-array)?

Comment: Or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3916857/access-vba-how-would-i-have-a-loop-in-vba-that-allows-me-to-loop-through-contr)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is.

Make sure each combobox is named the same, but with a corresponding integer at the end of each.  For example, the comboboxes should be named ComboBox1, ComboBox2, ComboBox3, ComboBox4, ComboBox5, and ComboBox6.

```
Private Sub Form_Initialize()
    Dim Table As ListObject
    Set Table = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").ListObjects("Table1")
    Dim Rows As Integer
    Rows = Table.ListRows.Count
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim j As Integer

    For j = 1 To 6
        With Me.Controls("ComboBox" & j)
            .Clear
            .Value = Empty
            For i = 1 To Rows
                .AddItem Table.DataBodyRange(i, 1)
            Next i
        End With
    Next j

End Sub
```

This should work everytime and is very useful when creating userforms etc..

Comment: Thank you, thankfully I had already named my controls in the fashion you mentioned., I had tried something similar but basically without the Me.Controls but that obviously didn't work.